# unable to run spring boot app it exits saying An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gson, jclouds

Whenever I try to run my spring boot application it runs until it finishes creating the entities inside the database and then it exits with the error

I tried to exclude Gson from Jcloudes, I tried to add Gson dependency explicitly, I tried to shade it in the on the apache jcloude, I tried all the solutions I could get by searching the web, and nothing worked
next is the maven pom.xml of the parent module:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>eagleboard-api</module>
    <module>eagleboard-services</module>
    <module>eagleboard-support</module>
    <module>eagleboard-web</module>
  </modules>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.eagleboard</groupId>
  <artifactId>eagleboard</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>eagleboard</name>
  <description>Eagleboard project</description>

  <properties>
    <rootDir></rootDir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <struts.version>2.3.36</struts.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.0</jackson.version>
    <geotools.version>18.0</geotools.version>
    <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
    <jclouds.version>2.0.3</jclouds.version>
    <jasperreports.version>6.3.1</jasperreports.version>
    <powermock.version>1.6.6</powermock.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <sel-ver>3.8.1</sel-ver>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <lettuce.version>4.5.0.Final</lettuce.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <!--<version>${hibernate.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OAuth 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
      <!--<version>${spring-security.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.lettuce/lettuce-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
      <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
      <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
      <version>${lettuce.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jasypt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other -->
    <!-- Javassist from hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>${struts.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javassist</groupId>
          <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
      <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
      <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>antlr</groupId>
          <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
          <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
          <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
          <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hisp</groupId>
      <artifactId>quick</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hisp</groupId>
      <artifactId>staxwax</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scijava</groupId>
      <artifactId>jep</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cronutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>cron-utils</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>logkit</groupId>
          <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Flyway -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache jClouds -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-blobstore</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>filesystem</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-s3</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Reporting -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xalan</groupId>
          <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>jfree</groupId>
          <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.19</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>gnujaxp</groupId>
          <artifactId>gnujaxp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.23</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>gnujaxp</groupId>
          <artifactId>gnujaxp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3.4.O</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>htmlparser</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>htmllexer</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GIS -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
      <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xalan</groupId>
          <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
      <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GeoTools -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-render</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xalan</groupId>
          <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-epsg-wkt</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SMS -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
      <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.jsmpp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsmpp</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openid4java</groupId>
      <artifactId>openid4java</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
          <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
      <artifactId>jzlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.jclouds.json.internal.DeserializationConstructorAndReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.<init>(DeserializationConstructorAndReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.<init>(Lcom/google/gson/internal/ConstructorConstructor;Lcom/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy;Lcom/google/gson/internal/Excluder;)V
```

The method's class, com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/D:/JavaEE_development/JavaEEMvnRepository/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar!/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/D:/JavaEE_development/JavaEEMvnRepository/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who face the same problem with jCloud, the problem is when you use `Gson` or guava or any library the included in `jcloud` dependency, you may use a particular version but `jcloud` use another version of the same libraries you use in your classpath which can cause class loading conflicts due to duplicate classes on the `classpath`. 
in my case, the conflicts were due to using `google-Gson` and `google-guava`

libraries in my code a new version, which also came with `jcloud` as an old version. The solution is to create a shaded jar file of the `jcloud` library in which you shade all the duplicated libraries you use in your `classPath`
I did this by creating a maven project which includes the following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>jcloud.eagleboard</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcloud-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <jclouds.version>2.1.2</jclouds.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-blobstore</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>filesystem</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-s3</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>com.shaded</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then I packaged it using the following command in the terminal:

```
mvn package
```

a file named `jcloud-shaded-1.0-SNAPSHOT` is then created inside the target directory, the name depends on the way you structure your shaded pom file.
copy that file to your project's home directory for example inside a directory called `local-maven-repo`.

then create the local repository and add to your project a dependency to the resulted jar file and the repository you created with the jar file inside

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./local-maven-repo/jcloud-shaded-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=jcloud.eagleboard -DartifactId=jcloud-shaded -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

and in my project pom file included the dependency to that local shaded jar:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>local-maven-repo</id>
      <url>file://${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

...
...

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>jcloud.eagleboard</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcloud-shaded</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to jclouds 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.  This includes fixes for [JCLOUDS-1166](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1166) and [JCLOUDS-1500](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1500) which will likely fix your symptoms.

Comment: couldn't upgrade to jcloud 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT, like it can't be found on maven, or if I get it wrong could you please clarify.

Comment: Visit https://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/ , select "Maven", and look at the "Daily builds" section.

Comment: I upgraded it but still, the same error keeps showing up